# Unit test UWP app with NUnit on VS2015

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, nunit, uwp

I spent far too much time trying to run a basic NUnit test on a Microsoft Store app. I installed NUnit v3.0.1 and NUnit3TestAdapter on VS2015 Pro but I get the following which confirms that the test is not discovered:

`------ Discover test started ------
NUnit Adapter 3.0.8.0 discovering tests is started
Exception NUnit.Engine.NUnitEngineException, Exception thrown discovering tests in <project exe file>
The NUnit 3.0 driver does not support the portable version of NUnit. Use a platform specific runner.
NUnit Adapter 3.0.8.0 discovering test is finished
========== Discover test finished: 0 found (0:00:01.0639991) ==========`

The NUnit.Engine.NUnitEngineException error referred to is not helpful because there is no way of exploring where the exception is in my program. The test is a single method with one Assert statement just to test if the setup works so there is nothing complicated. I also don't understand what a "platform specific runner" is. I installed both NUnit and NUnit3TestAdapter thru NuGet Package Manager and I presume installations for relevant platform and version are carried out.

I even tried out installing "NUnit Templates for Visual Studio". This allowed me to create an NUnit project, and interestingly the test within NUnit project is discovered and run. But the downside is that I cannot reference my UWP app project from the working NUnit project, I think because the NUnit project only supports .Net frameworks (up to 4.6.1) not Windows 10 platforms.

I have used NUnit before for non UWP applications without much trouble. Am I missing something or NUnit as yet doesn't support UWP apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you can only test DNX projects with XUnit.
[Here](https://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dnx.html) is a nice starting point for that.

From the official Asp.Net 5 [documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/testing/unit-testing.html#configuring-the-test-project-json) (which uses the same infrastructure as UWP):

> For example, to work with the xUnit test framework, you would
>   configure the dependencies as follows: [example project.json I dont
>   want to copy]
>   **As other test frameworks release support for DNX, we
>   will link to them here.**

Since there are no other frameworks linked in the documentation, I assume that there are none that support DNX projects at the moment.

Comment: But how is the DNX environment relevant to WinRT applications? I am a bit lost here.

Comment: From [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn894631.aspx): "apps that target the UWP can call not only the WinRT APIs that are common to all devices, but also APIs (including Win32 and .NET APIs) that are specific to the device family the app is running on."

Comment: @user2921851 With UWP you can target different frameworks, which I believe is the essence of DNX.

Comment: A simple question: can I not use NUnit with UWP app?

Comment: @user2921851 no, you cannot.

Comment: Thank you for that crystal clear answer. Do you know what Unit Test tools work and I should consider for UWP apps? Is XUnit, which I never used, the only one? So far, I only used NUnit. Sorry for prolonging this comment section into question.

Comment: @user2921851 At the moment XUnit is the only one. Dont worry, these frameworks are not vastly different,  you shouldnt have any problems learning XUnit.

Comment: Can you answer [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34657465/using-xunit-test-with-uwp-app-on-vs2015) please?

Answer (score 1):

Since this question was originally posted NUnit has developed it's support for testing UWP/Xamarin apps. Check out the [nunit.xamarin](https://github.com/nunit/nunit.xamarin) runners.

Essentially, your tests should be created in either a portable library, or a shared project. This can then be referenced by a UWP project runner, which can be run on the emulator.

If you take the shared project approach, you can also reference this through an .NET 4.5 project, which will allow your tests to integrate with the NUnit VS adapter, and show up in VS. Portable libraries can  not *yet* be run with this runner, however that's in the pipeline.